# Converting custom search filters to dynamic SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, search

I'm writing a custom search page that will allow people search for artwork, but I want to allow users to enter custom commands/tags into the search box to let them have direct control on filtering their results without having to use anything but the search box. Let me give an example...

I want the user to be able to type something like the following into a textbox:

```
Textbox Input: color=red|blue|green value>=5.00+<=10.00
```

Which would convert to the following SQL that I could peg onto the end of my SQL query:

```
AND (Artwork.Color = 'red' OR Artwork.Color = 'blue' OR Artwork.Color = 'green')
AND (Artwork.Price >= 50.00 AND Artwork.Price <= 100.00)
```

What do you think about...

1) Allowing people to type these custom commands into a textbox and converting these commands to SQL, is this normal practise? If not, how else would I allow advanced search options to be passed in, whilst keeping the page simple?

2) The best way to convert these custom commands into SQL, how do I convert an unknown number of filters split by potentially multiple operators (+,|)?

This is a web project built using ASP.NET (C#) and MSSQL. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you just convert these custom search parameters into dynamic SQL, you run a risk of SQL injection attacks. Is there no way you can use some kind of ORM (e.g. Linq-to-SQL)?

Comment: Using an ORM implies that you are trusting the user to type in correct syntax. What if I type in: shape=square|triangle and "shape" isn't a field in your data model?

Comment: Personally I've always gone down the route of creating a UI for all the search options wiht controls for valid input (checkbox lists,date pickers etc). Although this sounds a pain in the first place I think it works out the same once you've come up wiht the SQL ish systax, converted it and made it safe. Its also much more user friendly to non-geeks.

Comment: @Jon I am planning on creating such an interface, but on a separate page. I don't want to have the options there on the results page simply because they will take up so much space and I want the results to be the focus once the user has hit search.

Comment: @Sgt You can always hide the options in a hidden panel labelled "Search Options", then it can pop out when needed, and free up the screen when not.

Comment: @Jon I'm leaning towards this as a possible solution, it seems more and more complicated trying to do it the other way and I'm thinking I could use a jQuery slider to display the advanced options if the user needs them. If we did this then like you said the screen would be free most of the time unless the user wanted the advanced filters, in which case, focusing the user on the options they're wanting to change is actually a good thing. Thanks! :)

Comment: In that case, gonna turn the comments into an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I've always gone down the route of creating a UI for all the search options wiht controls for valid input (checkbox lists,date pickers etc). Although this sounds a pain in the first place I think it works out the same once you've come up wiht the SQL ish systax, converted it and made it safe. Its also much more user friendly to non-geeks.

You can always hide the options in a hidden panel labelled "Search Options", then it can pop out when needed, and free up the screen when not.

Comment: Thanks again for the help @Jon, I think this is a better, quicker and safer solution to my problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it is quite a [common](https://stackoverflow.com/search) [practice](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=136861). But of course not all websites allow this.
2. Come up with your own standardized way of defining search criteria. See the links in number 1.

Take a look at [ASP .NET Query Extender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.queryextender.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what SO and Google are allowing there is pretty much exactly what I want to achieve, I'll take a look at the query extender now.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, I don't think this is normal practice. It'll be difficult for normal users to remember this very specific search syntax. You may want to look at Google's [advanced search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en&authuser=0) page to see how they did something like this. That's the approach I have seen and used. If you are going to implement something like this, I think it'll be wise to still have a simplify free form text search. That way new users don't have to learn your syntax before being able to use your site.

Comment: Aha! Yes, I plan to have a separate "Advanced Search" page which will be a full page of standard form options, textboxes, dropdowns, checkboxes etc. The user can fill this form in and hit the search button, this will then convert their search into the format I showed in my question. The reason for doing all of this is because there are so many options on the advanced search page, the results page would look a little silly if I showed them all at the top, but I still wanted to give users the ability to ammend them from there.